# Content jumps horizontally whenever browser adds a scrollbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser, browser-scrollbars

I'm using a fixed width body and auto margins to center my content in the middle of the page.  When the content exceeds the page's height and the browser adds a scrollbar, the auto margins force the content to jump half the width of the scrollbar left.

Is comparing outerHeight with window.innerHeight an appropriate way of solving this?  Is there another way to solve this?

I think this should be enough info for the problem, but let me know if I can answer anything else.

Edit for clarification: I don't want to force the scrollbar to appear.

Comment: Then something like http://jdsharp.us/jQuery/minute/calculate-scrollbar-width.php might help

Answer (score 30):

I'll just leave this link here because it seems an elegant solution to me:

https://aykevl.nl/2014/09/fix-jumping-scrollbar

What he does is add this css:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 960px) {
    html {
        margin-left: calc(100vw - 100%);
        margin-right: 0;
    }
}
```

This will move the content to the left just the size of the scrollbar, so when it appears the content is already moved. This works for centered content with `overflow: auto;` applied to the `html` tag. The media query disables this for mobile phones, as its very obvious the difference in margin widths.

You can see an example here:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NPgbKP

Comment: Excellent! I didn't want *both* margins, so I applied a negative right margin instead: margin-right: calc(-100vw + 100%);
In addition, I had to kill the bottom scroll: overflow-x: hidden;

Comment: Note that this only works if there is an existing whitespace margin to the left of your content.

Comment: Good answer @ulu you should post it.

Comment: This is great. Now how can I do it on a div which has `overflow: auto`? Is there an equivalent to `100vw` for elements which are not themselves the full width of the viewport?

Answer (score 10):

Use this CSS:

```
body { overflow-y: scroll; }
```

Answer (score 6):

I've run into this problem myself and I've found two ways to solve it:

1. Always force the scrollbar to be present:
   `body { overflow-y: scroll; }` Setting it on the `html` doesn't work in all browsers or might give *double* scroll bars if the scrollbar does appear.
2. Add a class that adds ~30 pixels to the right margin of your page if there is no scrollbar.

I've chosen option 1 but I'm not sure if it works in all browsers (especially the older ones).

Facebook uses option 2.

Comment: Option 1 works on all browsers, older browsers include the scroll on all pages by default.  Facebook does #2 because they don't want the scroll bar to show if it's not necessary.

Comment: I think it gives the problem of _double_ scroll bars on some browsers (the scrollbar will be in the `body`). It's been a while, I really don't want to test this again :P

Comment: Ah yes... but what if I don't want to force scrollbars?  What if I want the browser to not have a scrollbar when it doesn't need one?

Comment: Readers can't use option 2 if you omit the actual hard part of the solution... (I know what you probably used, but this is just an incomplete answer...)

Answer (score 3):

You can force the scrollbar to always appear:

http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/css/scroll-always.html

Comment: See my edit.  I don't want to force scrollbars when not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

The process is :

```
html {
   overflow-y: scroll !important;
}
```

This will show the scrollbar even there no need any scroll bar.

Answer (score 0):

Best possible way through CSS, It will show/hide Scrollbar accordingly, will
solve jump problem, works on every browser

```
html {
    overflow: hidden;
 }

body {
    overflow-y: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;
}
```

Comment: "overflow: hidden" on the html node prevents the browser from remembering the scoll state when using the navigation buttons

Answer (score 0):

For me, the solution was to add this rule to the body:

```
body {
  overflow-anchor: none;
}
```

This rule was added recently, and aims to reduce the variability of browsers having different default assumptions about how they should react to overflowing. Chrome, for example, has overflow anchoring enabled by default, whereas Firefox does not. Setting this property will force both browsers to behave the same way.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-anchor

Comment: Interesting property that I didn't know about, but it's not actually related to the question (which is about the layout changing when the scrollbars appears, not about the scroll position changing when the content changes)